# Getting the list of files in a SharePoint document library and create entries of file names in a list using c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a document library containing folders and files. I would like to get the name of files and folders to store in a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the items property on a SPList object. You can then access the name by accessing the name property of the item's file property. For example:

```
var items = docLib.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    string fileName = item.File.Name;
    ....
}
```

There are other ways to do this but this is probably the most easy method.